# Link the IBOutlets when creating an instance of UIView using a NIB file

Tags: uiview, subclass, nib, iboutlet

I have created a `UIView` object using the contents of a NIB file like this:

```
self.results = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ResultsView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
self.results.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 500);
```

But `self.results` is a subclass of `UIView` actually:

```
@interface GameResultsView : UIView {
  UILabel *title;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *title;

@end
```

I have connected the `title` attribute defined in `GameResults` with a `UILabel` object through Interface Builder. But during execution the application stops with a `SIGABRT` message when the view is assigned to `self.results`:

```
-[UILabel copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c2f780
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c2f780'
```

It seems like the label cannot be connected at all. What's the right way of doing this (if any)? My purpose here is add this custom view to a `UIScrollView` object.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I'm using Xcode 4

Comment: @elitalon are you using XCode3 or 4?

Comment: @Nick Weaver I'm using Xcode 4

Comment: @elitalon select your custom view GameResultsView in IB, then open the Utilities and then select the identity inspector. What does the Custom Class field say?

Comment: @Nick Weaver I have set it to GameResultsView.

Comment: @elitalon have you synthesized the accessor methods for the label? Is self.results of the type GameResultsView *? Can you make sure that the NSBundle/loadNibNamed returns your view and is of the correct class?

Comment: @Nick Weaver Yes, I have synthesized it and the attribute is of class GameResultsView. However, it seems the loadNibNamed method is not returning the expected value. I'll let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the nib like this:

```
UINib * nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:aName bundle:nil];

NSArray * nibContent = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];

for (id aView in nibContent) {
    if ([aView isKindOfClass:[GameResultsView class]]) {
         return aView;
    }
}
```

This will return the first occurence of a GameResultsView.

Comment: The key step was passing an actual object to `instantiateWithOwner:` method. I should pass `self.results` as parameter, after allocate it and initialize it